# Replacing special characters with java

Tags: java, special-characters

I want to replace all ♭ and ♯.

Characters aren`t found using

```
values.replace("♭", "b");
```

or

```
values.replace("\u266D", "b");
```

How do I reference those characters/ special characters in general in Java?

Comment: Can you show us the sysout of `values`?

Comment: Strings are immutable so are you assigning back the result of the replace operation? I.e are you doing `values = values.replace("♭", "b");` or just `values.replace("♭", "b");`?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I reference those characters/ special characters in general in Java?

You can do this:

```
[\W_]
```

That will match all those and special characters including _